# Generating Windows Touch Events in Java

Tags: java, windows, touch, multi-touch

I have an application written in Java which processes TUIO messages to interact with tangible objects on a tabletop. Now I want this application to also recognize simple touch events. How do I create multiple windows touch events in Java? (e.g. The user should also use his fingers as an cursor on the tabletop) I desire the same behaviour as in the [BSQSimulator](https://code.google.com/p/bsqsimulator/).